# Issue with POST JSON with list of strings to a Jersey REST service

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm new to Jersey REST service and I'm currently tyring to post a JSON with list of strings inside using POSTMAN without any success so far.

The JSON I'm trying to post is a Question object:

```
{
    "answers":["I don't know","Maybe","No","Yes"],
    "correct":"Yes",
    "question":"Are you learning Android?"
}
```

The Post method is consuming a Question object, setting the correct answer to "CORRECT" and producing the Question object as a JSON:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("add")
public Question getAllItems(Question question) {
    question.setCorrect("CORRECT");
    return question;
}
```

So when I post a JSON via Postamn, the JSON I'm getting back comes without the List of strings I sent it, as it should:

```
{
    "correct":"CORRECT",
    "question":"Are you learning Android?"
}
```

The JSON that I expect to be produced by the REST Service:

```
{
    "answers":["I don't know","Maybe","No","Yes"],
    "correct":"CORRECT",
    "question":"Are you learning Android?"
}
```

The Question Class has three fields (String represents question, String represent the correct answer and List of Strings represents the possible answers):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Question {

private String question;
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

private List<String> answers;

@XmlElement
public List<String> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}

public void setAnswers(List<String> answers) {
    if(this.answers == null){
        this.answers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.answers.clear();
    this.answers.addAll(answers);
    Collections.shuffle(this.answers);
}

public void setAnswers(String[] answers) {
    if(this.answers == null){
        this.answers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.answers.clear();
    this.answers.addAll(Arrays.asList(answers));
    Collections.shuffle(this.answers);
}

private String correct;
public String getCorrect() {
    return correct;
}
public void setCorrect(String correct) {
    this.correct = correct;
}

public Question() {}

public Question(String question, List<String> answers, String correct){
    this.question = question;
    this.correct = correct;
    this.answers = new ArrayList<>(answers);
}

public Question(String question, String[] answers, String correct){
    this.question = question;
    this.correct = correct;
    this.answers = new ArrayList<>();
    setAnswers(answers);
}

}
```

Comment: what does happen if `List<String> answers` changed to `String[] answers`..?

Comment: From the code above I can't see if question's Answers are set, is that the case?

Comment: @nafas There are two set Methods, one that's getting a List<String> and one that gets String[], when debugging the setAnswers(List<String> answers) is called and is getting a null List, so the answers field in the Question object is empty

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I changed the getAnswers to return a String[] instead of List and it worked.

```
@XmlElement
public String[] getAnswers() {
    String[] temp = new String[answers.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        temp[i] = answers.get(i);
    }
    return temp;
}
```